# KSZ8081RNACA phy address setting up

Tags: pic, ethernet

I have following PCB design, which use PIC32MZ2048EFH144 and KSZ8081RNACA, I want to set up phy address to be 3.

From document it has following words "Config Mode: The pull-up/pull-down value is latched as PHYAD[1:0] at the de-assertion of reset.",

which can be found at following link: https://docs.rs-online.com/583f/0900766b8141ed48.pdf

How to get into config mode?

What are the steps to configure this chip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is simply indicating that the chip reads and latches this value when coming out of reset. In other words, when coming out of reset, the chip enters configuration mode briefly before entering normal operational mode.

All you need to do is add a pull up, pull down or none as shown on page 10 of your document. For a value of 3, add the pull-up resistor.